# disable linter in DAML studio

Tags: daml

Is it possible to disable the linter that daml studio seems to be applying since `~0.13.18ish` as the warnings are visually distracting in the IDE.

Eg: when writing choice names with an underscore.

`Warning: use of camelCase`

I've tried adding a `.dlint` file in project root but had no effect

`- ignore: {name: 'Use camelCase'}`

On investigation it seems its built into damlc within the LSP implementation but cant specifically override it with a `.daml.yaml` within daml studio itself?

https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/blob/master/compiler/damlc/daml-ide-core/dlint.yaml

https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/issues/2386

Since all choice names must be unique, namespacing with an underscore as per the docs recommendation `TemplateName_ChoiceName` is what I feel to be the best approach to naming choices.

Is there anything I may be doing incorrectly or any advice on how to configure daml studio to accept a linting config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a '.dlint.yaml' file (you were so close!) in the project root with contents

```
- ignore: {name: Use camelCase}
```

and restarting Visual Studio will disable the warning at the project level. Alternatively, a '.dlint.yaml' in your `$HOME` directory will disable that warning once and for all for all projects.

Lastly, if you would prefer to leave the option enabled for the project generally but turn it off in a subset of the project files (`Foo.daml` and `Bar.daml` say), you can use the syntax

```
- ignore: {name: Use camelCase, within: [Foo, Bar]}}
```